# Default user in session Point of Sale ODOO 10

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-10, point-of-sale

I have a problem in version 10 of odoo
In the cofiguration > user page "point of sale" the field **'Default Point of Sale'** field is gone
while 
in version 8 and 9 we can create several sessions with different users what is the solution
As the picture below in link 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOwoe.png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]In odoo10 we can also create different sessions in POS. But here this configuration is not located likewise in odoo8 & odoo9. As shown in image this feature is there under **Point of Sale >> Configuraion >> Point of Sale** In that you can see **"Create"** button. From there you can create multiple sessions.